# How to perform delete on a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, zoneddatetime

**ISSUE:**

- I have table `[ INFOTABLE ]` with a timestamp column named `DATETIMESTAMP` [INTEGER] datatype.
- I need to delete records using this column but delete query throws error.
- It is mainly because of the T [TIME indicator] inbetween the timestamp captured. [Eg:] `2020-01-01T17:45:31.127452+03:00[Asia/Riyadh]`

**SQLITE TABLE:**

```
  String create_sql3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Tablename3 + "("
                    + SNO + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + ITEM + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                    + DATETIMESTAMP + " INTEGER DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )";
```

**DELETE QUERY:**

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Tablename3 + " WHERE DATETIMESTAMP = " + Integer.parseInt(deltimestamp.get(y))  + ";");
```

**EXCEPTION LOGGED:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
unrecognized token: "01T17" (code 1):,while compiling: DELETE
FROM INFOTABLE WHERE DATATIMESTAMP = 2020-01-01T17:45:31.127452+03:00[Asia/Riyadh];
```

Here `deltimestamp` is a String Arraylist which has datetimestamps as String. Appreciate help on Delete query correction for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column!

Comment: Save the table as timestamp(Long Value : 1231413123)
It will be easier for you to query the relevant values ​​during the deletion process.

Comment: Hi @kzncrda! This one you say uses Java.time?

Comment: yes. 

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println(timestamp.getTime());

Comment: @kzncrda timestamp is from java.sql. What I store in table is zoneddatetime [Java.time].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed the issue!**

**QUERY (ERROR):**

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Tablename3 + " WHERE DATETIMESTAMP = " + Integer.parseInt(deltimestamp.get(y))  + ";");
```

**QUERY (FIXED):**

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Tablename3 + " WHERE DATETIMESTAMP = " + "'" + deltimestamp.get(y)  + "'" + ";");
```

**OR**

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Tablename3 + " WHERE DATETIMESTAMP = "+ "'" + cursor.getString(7) + "'" + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the table as timestamp(Long Value : 1231413123) It will be easier for you to query the relevant values ​​during the deletion process.

Sample Table;

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Foo TEXT,
        Bar TEXT,
        Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```